# WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Tags: appium-android

I want to perform click and scroll down action on a element . 
* Already i tried with Action class
* javascript executor.
* Robot class

First I am trying to click on element and hold it for a while and then scroll till expected element finds but I am getting error as method has not yet been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

1.The above error comes when your app is not matching with the current context
2.According to your code there is a need of context change of app environment you can change context using `driver.context("YOUR APP CONTEXT NAME")` 
3.Some times there must be error in your code like it is not locating correct element or may be you are using unwanted method

Try above 2 points it might help you
if it is not working sorry for wasting your Testing time

Happy Testing